# How to get TEntity by name

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I need to get all TEntitys from mi DbContext to extract all information from each table. I have little tables with little information.
I have this code but don´t work.

```
var dbSetPropertiesLocal = local.GetDbSetProperties();                

foreach (var item in dbSetPropertiesLocal)
{
    Type type = item.PropertyType; // This need get the type of the actual TEntity
    var enumerable = GetLocal<type>(item.Name, local);  
}
```

This method returns all data from the specified DbSet by name and te specified DbContext

```
public List<TEntity> GetLocal<TEntity>(string name, DbContext ctx)
{
    var enumerable = (IEnumerable<TEntity>)(typeof([ClassNameOfMyContext]).GetProperty(name).GetValue(ctx, null));
    return enumerable.ToList();
}
```

This method get the properties from my DbContext. I use this for get all DbSets in my DbContext

```
public static List<PropertyInfo> GetDbSetProperties(this DbContext context)
{
    var dbSetProperties = new List<PropertyInfo>();
    var properties = context.GetType().GetProperties();

    foreach (var property in properties)
    {
        var setType = property.PropertyType;
        var isDbSet = setType.IsGenericType && (typeof(IDbSet<>).IsAssignableFrom(setType.GetGenericTypeDefinition()) || setType.GetInterface(typeof(IDbSet<>).FullName) != null);

        if (isDbSet)
            dbSetProperties.Add(property);
    }

    return dbSetProperties;
}
```

Comment: The purpose of this code is to get all data from every entity in your dbcontext?

Comment: yes, I am doing a database synchronizer

Comment: Isn't it a lot easier just to use `context.Set<T>().ToList();` therefor like `context.Set<Users>().ToList()`

Comment: But I do not know how many Entities in my DbContext, so I need to do generic.

Comment: Can you use a third party library or you are limited? Finding all tables / properties can be kinda hard when you add TPC, TPH and TPT inheritance.

Comment: Use this: https://efmappingapi.codeplex.com/ - gives you metadata about EF tables. Though for DB-synchroniser EF is not the best solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if your current path is the best way to solve your bigger problem (implementing a database synchronizer). But here is a solution to your smaller problem (calling your generic code).

Instead of an extension method, create a generic class, and create an instance using reflection. Also, add an interface to talk to the instance. Remember, the class might be generic, but if you have to talk to it from non-generic code, then you need an interface to convert from a generic class instance to a non-generic interface instance (if you know what I mean).

```
public interface ILocalEntityListProvider {
    List<object> GetLocal(string name, DbContext ctx);
}
public class LocalEntityListProvider<TEntity> : ILocalEntityListProvider {
    private IEnumerable<TEntity> GetLocal(string name, DbContext ctx)
    {
        return (IEnumerable<TEntity>)(typeof([ClassNameOfMyContext])
            .GetProperty(name)
            .GetValue(ctx, null));
    }

    List<object> ILocalEntityListProvider.GetLocal(string name, DbContext ctx) {
        return GetLocal(name, ctx)
            .Cast<object>()
            .ToList();
    }
}

var dbSetPropertiesLocal = local.GetDbSetProperties();                
foreach (var item in dbSetPropertiesLocal)
{
    var entityType = item.PropertyType.GenericTypeArguments.First();
    var providerClassType = typeof(LocalEntityListProvider<>).MakeGeneric(entityType);
    var providerInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(providerClassType) as ILocalEntityListProvider;
    var enumerable = providerInstance.GetLocal(item.Name, local);  
}
```

Note: I haven't tested this, but I have used the principle many times.

Comment: "Type does not contain a definition for "Make Generic" and no extension method that accepts a first argument of type "Type" found"

Comment: It should be Type.MakeGenericType. I'll fix it later.

Comment: I tried using your solution and throws me the following error:
You can not convert an object of type 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1 [myEntity]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1 [System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1 [myEntity]]'.

Comment: Yes, i can see now. Fixed I think, not sure, on my phone at the moment, can you check?

Comment: I hope you give me the solution, I'd appreciate it a lot and mark your answer.

Comment: Ok, I'll have to try it on laptop later.

Comment: Tank you so much @Maarten

Comment: @Richard Fixed. The retrieval of the entity-type was incorrect.